# Remove The Json Value From Json

Tags: android, json

I want to remove json value from below json file .

**This is my json object :**

```
{
  "Approximation": {
    "name": "Approximation",
    "description": [
      "Approximation",
      "Approximation",
      "Approximation"
    ],
    "video": [
      "evideo/package1/maths/Approximation/349188_f2ba28819a74355a456ef91d95451b71/349188_f2ba28819a74355a456ef91d95451b71/349188.mpd",
      "evideo/package3/maths/approxomation/396183_Approximation/396183_fcedf516e0f5c935d561d486058fa6e0/396183.mpd",
      "evideo/package2/maths/approxomation/387010_01approximation/387010_949440b1082fea19faa7dcb4aebf0b43/387010.mpd"
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is what I'm trying

**Code :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            jsonArr.remove(i);
            children = new ArrayList<ChildrenEvent>();
            et = new Events(jsonObj.optString("name"));
            ct = new ChildrenEvent(jsonObj.optString("description"));
            langs.add(et);
            children.add(ct);
  }
```

Comment: so whats your question ??

Comment: i want to remove the word "Approximation": from the json and save in the list array in the app

Comment: Under which key? There are many occurrences of "Approximation" in the `JSON`.

Comment: {"Approximation":{"name":"Approximation","description":[]}} the starting one. when array is generated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. You don't need to remove the key "Approximation" to get the data.

This is how you parse this `JSON`.

```
{
    "Approximation": {
        "name": "Approximation",
        "description": ["Approximation", "Approximation", "Approximation"],
        "video": ["evideo/package1/maths/Approximation/349188_f2ba28819a74355a456ef91d95451b71/349188_f2ba28819a74355a456ef91d95451b71/349188.mpd", "evideo/package3/maths/approxomation/396183_Approximation/396183_fcedf516e0f5c935d561d486058fa6e0/396183.mpd", "evideo/package2/maths/approxomation/387010_01approximation/387010_949440b1082fea19faa7dcb4aebf0b43/387010.mpd"]
    }
}
```

Code,

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(json_string);
JSONObject appproxObj = mainObj.getJSONObject("Approximation");

// Parse name
String name = appproxObj.getString("name");
et = new Events(name);
langs.add(et);

// Parse descriptions
JSONArray descriptions = appproxObj.getJSONArray("description");
children = new ArrayList<ChildrenEvent>();
for (int i = 0; i < descriptions.length(); i++ ) {
    String description = descriptions.getString(i);
    ct = new ChildrenEvent(description);
    children.add(ct);       
}
```

Still if you need the `JSON` without key "Approximation", the variable `appproxObj` has the `JSON` without the key.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in JsonObject, that is remove(). It will help you to remove any key from jsonObject;

Use this:-

```
jsonObject.remove("key");
```